# how to stop react-p5-wrapper running in background

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, p5.js

I faced an issue with `react-p5-wrapper` that it is running in background although I have switch to another route in my react app.

For example, I am currently in `/game`, and the console is logging `"running draw"`, but when I switch to `/about-us`, it still logging, meaning it is still running the draw function

[Here is my code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-p5-problem-vmoi4?file=/src/game.js)

**App.js**

```js
    import "./styles.css";
    import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    export default function App() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <Link to="/game">Game</Link> | <Link to="/about-us">About Us</Link>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/about-us" component={require("./abtus").default} />
                        <Route path="/game" component={require("./game").default} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**game.js**

```js
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { ReactP5Wrapper, P5Instance } from "react-p5-wrapper";

    // Sound
    let pointSound, endSound;
    let playEndSound = false;

    /**
    * @param {P5Instance} p
    */
    const sketch = (p) => {
        const MAX_SPEED = 15;

        const pickDirections = () => {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1));
        };

        const randomXPos = () => {
            return p.random(30, p.width - 30);
        };

        const ramdomImgIndex = () => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);
        };

        const reset = () => {
            score = 0;
            speed = 2;
            falls = [
                {
                    y: -70,
                    x: randomXPos(),
                    rotation: 0,
                    direction: pickDirections(),
                    imgIndex: ramdomImgIndex()
                }
            ];
        };

        const rotate_n_draw_image = (image,img_x,img_y,img_width,img_height,img_angle) => {
            p.imageMode(p.CENTER);
            p.translate(img_x + img_width / 2, img_y + img_width / 2);
            p.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * img_angle);
            p.image(image, 0, 0, img_width, img_height);
            p.rotate((-Math.PI / 180) * img_angle);
            p.translate(-(img_x + img_width / 2), -(img_y + img_width / 2));
            p.imageMode(p.CORNER);
        };

        // Images
        let imgs = [],
            basket = { img: null, width: 150, height: 150 },
            imgSize = 50;

        let screen = 0,
            falls = [
                {
                    y: -70,
                    x: randomXPos(),
                    rotation: 0,
                    direction: pickDirections(),
                    imgIndex: ramdomImgIndex()
                }
            ],
            score = 0,
            speed = 2;

        const startScreen = () => {
            p.background(205, 165, 142);
            p.fill(255);
            p.textAlign(p.CENTER);
            p.text("WELCOME TO MY CATCHING GAME", p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            p.text("click to start", p.width / 2, p.height / 2 + 20);
            reset();
        };

        const gameOn = () => {
            p.background(219, 178, 157);
            p.textAlign(p.LEFT);
            p.text("score = " + score, 30, 20);
    
            falls = falls.map(({ x, y, rotation, direction, imgIndex }) => {
                // rotate while dropping
                rotation += direction;

                // dropping
                y += speed;

                return { x, y, rotation, direction, imgIndex };
            });

            falls.forEach(({ x, y, rotation, imgIndex }, i) => {
                // when is lower than the border line
                if (y > p.height) {
                    screen = 2;
                    playEndSound = true;
                }

                // when reaching the border line and is within the range
                if (
                    y > p.height - 50 &&
                    x > p.mouseX - basket.width / 2 &&
                    x < p.mouseX + basket.width / 2
                ) {
                    // Play Sound
                    pointSound.currentTime = 0;
                    pointSound.play();
                    // Increase Score
                    score += 10;

                    // Increase Speed
                    if (speed < MAX_SPEED) {
                        speed += 0.1;
                        speed = parseFloat(speed.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    // Whether add new item into array or not
                    if (i === falls.length - 1 && falls.length < 3) {
                        falls.push({
                            x: randomXPos(),
                            y: -70 - p.height / 3,
                            rotation: 0,
                            direction: pickDirections(),
                            imgIndex: ramdomImgIndex()
                        });
                    }
                    falls[i].y = -70;
                    falls[i].x = randomXPos();
                    falls[i].imgIndex = ramdomImgIndex();
                }

                rotate_n_draw_image(imgs[imgIndex], x, y, imgSize, imgSize, rotation);
            });
            p.imageMode(p.CENTER);
            p.image(
                basket.img,
                p.mouseX,
                p.height - basket.height / 2,
                basket.width,
                basket.height
            );
        };

        const endScreen = () => {
            if (playEndSound) {
                endSound.play();
                playEndSound = false;
            }

            p.background(205, 165, 142);
            p.textAlign(p.CENTER);
            p.text("GAME OVER", p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            p.text("SCORE = " + score, p.width / 2, p.height / 2 + 20);
            p.text("click to play again", p.width / 2, p.height / 2 + 60);
        };

        p.preload = () => {
            // Load Images
            imgs[0] = p.loadImage("https://dummyimage.com/400x400");
            imgs[1] = p.loadImage("https://dummyimage.com/400x400");
            imgs[2] = p.loadImage("https://dummyimage.com/401x401");
            basket.img = p.loadImage("https://dummyimage.com/500x500");
        };

        p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(
                window.innerWidth > 400 ? 400 : window.innerWidth,
                window.innerHeight > 500 ? 500 : window.innerHeight
            );
        };

        p.draw = () => {
            console.log("running draw");
            switch (screen) {
                case 0:
                    startScreen();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gameOn();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    endScreen();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        };

        p.mousePressed = () => {
            if (screen === 0) {
                screen = 1;
            } else if (screen === 2) {
                screen = 0;
            }
        };
    };
    const CatchingGmae = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            pointSound = new Audio("/game/points.wav");
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            endSound = new Audio("/game/end.wav");
            pointSound.volume = 0.3;
            return () => {
                pointSound.muted = true;
                endSound.muted = true;
            };
        });

        return (
            <div className="mx-auto flex justify-center items-center">
                <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch} />
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default CatchingGame;
```

Is there anyway to stop it from running in background when user switches route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your setup, I can see two ways of telling the sketch to stop when route is switched and the Game react component is not rendered anymore.

> **Alt 1**. You can make something similar to [react-p5-wrapper
> documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper#reacting-to-props), reacting to props:
>
> In CatchingGmae component:
>
> ```
> const [lastRender, setLastRender] = useState(Date.now());
>
> useEffect(() => {
>  const interval = setInterval(() => setLastRender(Date.now()), 100);
>
>  return () => {
>    clearInterval(interval);
>  };
> }, []);
>
> return (
>   <>
>     <div className="mx-auto flex justify-center items-center">
>       <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch} lastRender={lastRender} />
> ```
>
> In sketch:
>
> ```
>  let lastRender = 0;
>  p.updateWithProps = (props) => {
>    lastRender = props.lastRender;
>  };
>
>  p.draw = () => {
>    if (!(Date.now() > lastRender + 100)) {
>      console.log("running draw");
> ```

☝ The problem with the **Alt 1** is that react will do calculations and re-render frequently for no reason.

> **Alt 2**. Use a state outside of React, a very simple side-effect
> for the component, for the sketch to poll on.
>
> Add to CatchingGmae component:
>
> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>   window.noLoop = false;
>
>   return () => {
>     window.noLoop = true;
>   };
> }, []);
> ```
>
> Inside p.draw:
>
> ```
>  if (window.noLoop) return p.noLoop();
> ```

☝ This works without calculations, but you might want to scope the global within your own namespace or using other state manager.

Comment: Thanks! I use the 2nd method and it works perfectly! It also stop the draw function before the route change!